# How can I navigate to another page, from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with one button. When clicked, that button navigates to http://google.com/

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  window.location="http://google.com";
});
```

I would like this navigation to work when this page is embedded within the iframe. I don't want to affect the outside host page, but rather only the contents of the iframe. What's a good cross-platform way to:

1. Detect if I'm contained in an iframe
2. If not, navigate like above.
3. If yes, navigate the iframe only?

(I'm going to try to implement the algorithm I just described, but regardless I think this question is interesting enough to be posted. If I succeed, I'll post my solution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Detect if I'm contained in an iframe

```
if (window != window.top) { 
    // the page is inside an iframe
}
```

> 2) If not, navigate like above.

navigate like above

> 3) If yes, navigate the iframe only?

When you write `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';` you are navigating the contents of the iframe, not that of the top page. If you want to navigate the top page, you can only do this if this top page is on the same domain as the iframe and you could use `window.top.location.href`.

---

UPDATE:

There is a security mechanism built in browsers which forbid you from redirecting to sites that set the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` response header when inside an iframe. That's the case with `http://www.google.com`. Simply navigate to this site and look at the response HTTP headers with FireBug or developer toolbar you are using and you will see this header. You cannot redirect to it and you will get the following error message:

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

It's basically a security mechanism implemented by some sites whose authors didn't want you to embed them in an iframe.

Comment: I want to make only the iframe content navigate away, not the top domain. Doing `window.location=url` didn't work for me.

Comment: @ripper234, what happens when you use `window.location` from **inside** the iframe? Is the script running inside the iframe or not? I begin to suspect that it is not if you way that this redirects the top page.

Comment: The script is running from **inside** the iframe. The browser (chrome) displays a short "loading" animation (like when loading a new page), only it doesn't actually navigate away.

Comment: In Firefox, the content of the iframe becomes blank.

Comment: And in IE 8, I get "This content cannot be displayed in a frame". I didn't even know some pages cannot be displayed in an iframe.

Comment: @ripper234, that happens because you are trying to redirect to http://www.google.com and this site sets the `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` response header. When the browser encounters this header it stops the redirect if the requesting page is contained inside an iframe. That's basically a frame busting mechanism. Sites like google do not like to be embedded inside iframes and there's not much you could do about it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. I thought this was a general problem and that navigating from within an iframe simply requires different JS.

Comment: Now I wonder if there's a decent way to detect this. I think most sites I will navigate to won't have this header, but I would want to check it just to be sure, and display an error message in that case. Wonder if the thing to do is do a separate ajax get request ... it's a little too ugly just for navigation.

Comment: @ripper234, you cannot detect this from javascript due to the same origin policy which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX request. The only reliable way to detect this is to perform an HTTP request to the url you are intending to redirect from your server side script and read the response headers. Then based on the presence of the given header you would adapt the HTML page that you are generating and not try to redirect in case of this header.